# How to find Django template tags and replace them with block tags in Vim?

Tags: parsing, vim, django-templates, replace

I need to change several instances of Django templates that look
like this:

```
{% block content %}{{ mycontents }}{% endblock content %}
```

to this:

```
{% templatetag openblock %} block content {% templatetag closeblock %}{% templatetag openvariable %} mycontents {% templatetag closevariable %}{% templatetag openblock %} endblock content {% templatetag closeblock %}
```

How can I construct a find-and-replace command to do this? I usually use Vim for this kind of thing, but I'm open to other alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the following two substitution commands for transforming
the block and variable contents respectively:

```
:%s/{%\(.\{-}\)%}/{% openblock %}\1{% closeblock %}/g
:%s/{{\(.\{-}\)}}/{% openvariable %}\1{% closevariable %}/g
```

Comment: Update the template tag placeholders and you'll have a complete answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do it with a macro. this will only work if "mycontents" are all on one line

save macro with:

`:let @q='/{% block
wcwtemplatetagw"aciwopenblockf}a block a {% templatetag closeblock %}{% templatetag openvariable %}l2dlf}C{% templatetag closevariable %}{% templatetag openblock %} endblock a {% templatetag closeblock %}'`

and `@q` to use

edit ooookkkk I should have guessed that pasting special characters from vim wouldn't work